# How does reflector show types when Assembly.GetTypes() fails due to a missing referenced assembly

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a broken Assembly that I want to reflect over, its not broken badly, it just cannot find a referenced assembly, so it does fail a PEVerify. But....Assembly.LoadFrom() will still load it and GetTypes() will throw a ReflectionTypeLoadException, the .LoaderExceptions array shows me what referenced assembly cannot be found. At this point I am roadblocked.

However, the great little tool Reflector is able to go further and actually display the contained types, and handles gracefully the missing reference issue by giving me a pop-up dialog to browse for it. My question is, How after the GetTypes() fails does reflector manage to get the types anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reflector doesn't use System.Reflection to analyse an assembly.

I don't know which library Reflector uses, but you might want to have a look at [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil).

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I am not trying to resolve the assembly, I am wanting to get all the type (names) despite the unresolved reference.

Comment: Ah, I'll have a look at that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`Module.GetTypes()` will throw this same exception.  If you catch a `ReflectionTypeLoadException` from the `Assembly.GetTypes()` call, that exception will have a "Types" property on it of all the types that it could load.  The ones that it couldn't will be detailed in a list/array property called `LoaderExceptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this will help, but perhaps try getting the the modules first and then the types from there.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(brockenAssembly);

Module[] mList = a.GetModules();

for (int i = 0; i < mList.length; i++)
{
     Module m = a.GetModules()[i];
     Type[] tList = m.GetTypes();

}
```

Hope fully you could get the list of types available in one of the modules.